# Finding nearest element to a line in a two-dimensional array

Tags: list-manipulation, nearest

I have a 2-dimensional list of data of $x$ and $y$ coordinates. I am looking for a way to get the element of the list which has the closest $y$ value to a given $y$ value. I tried using `Nearest`, but this only gives me the nearest $y$ value to the value that I am looking for, but not an element of the form `{x, y}`. I am sure this can't be a great problem, I just do not see how to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you add an example of your code and result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is much simpler than the title suggests

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]
y = RandomReal[]

Graphics[
 Point @ pts,
 GridLines -> {None, {y}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize@7, 
   Point@First@MinimalBy[pts, Abs[#[[2]] - y] &]}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A way to use `Nearest`:

Using @Kuba's setup:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]
y = RandomReal[];

nF = Nearest[pts[[All, 2]] -> Automatic]; 
(* nF =  Nearest[pts[[All, 2]] -> "Index"] in versions 10+ *)
Graphics[{Point@pts, Red, AbsolutePointSize@7, Point[pts[[First @ nF @ y]]]}, 
 GridLines -> {None, {y}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Region*` functions:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

With[{pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 10]},
 Manipulate[
  line = Line[{pt1, pt2}];
  sel = First@MinimalBy[pts, RegionDistance[line, #] &];
  rn = RegionNearest[line, sel];
  Graphics[{
    Blue, AbsolutePointSize[6]
    , Black, line
    , Point@pts
    , Red, Point@sel
    , Black, Dashed
    , Line[{sel, rn}]
    , Circle[]
    }
   , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
   , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
   , Frame -> True
   ]
  , {{pt1, {-3/4, -3/4}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}
  , {{pt2, {3/4, 3/4}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}
  , TrackedSymbols :> All
  , ContentSize -> {400, 400}
  ]
 ]
```

---

[image]